# Labels inside of horizontal stack view are of equal width?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I have a stack view with these properties:
Axis: Vertical
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill

I add other horizontal stack views to that vertical one with the below properties:
Axis: Horizontal
Alignment: FirstBaseline
Distribution: Fill

Each one of those horizontal stack views contain two labels. I want the labels to shrink/expand their widths according to the text inside of them. Whenever I set their numberOfLines to 0, both labels have equal widths, and the increase happens in the height, If I set numberOfLines to 1, they expand/shrink their widths according to the text, but if the text requires more than one line, the rest of the text doesn't appear. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: add your code to the question

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? I’m unclear how the resultant behavior differs from what you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, two labels inside horizontal stackview. label1 with numberOfLines = 1 and label2 was multiline. (numberOfLines = 0) both labels were having equal width even if label 2 had a much longer text!

To fix this issue I had to set a width constraint(based on its current content) for label1 with priority = 750 (high but not required).
This way if the label has a long text and its width grows bigger than that constraint then label width = its content size.
if label width is smaller than the constraint then label width = constraint.

[See screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2OvW.png)

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 labels, with number of lines set to `1`, next to each other, trying to fit in a stack view of 200 pixels, but each label needs 150 pixels, you have to solve the problem:

> Which label is compressed and which gets its full width?

This depends on their compression resistance priorities. Auto-layout won't compress both of them equally by default, you'd need to set their constraints to have equal  width).

It looks like `UIStackView` struggles to get the layout constraints of the label if you set the number of lines to `0`. If their text is of different lengths then it seems to lose all sense of itself. In this case I'd suggest to set the widths of the 2 labels to be equal, unless that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Autolayout yet struggling to determine width of label inside StackView, when number of lines is 0. My workaround is to set preferred width.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem , I set below properties for both the UILabels and it worked for me

```
label1.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
label1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

label2.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
label2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

When Priority is set to .required ,it prevents any shrinking as there should be nothing more important.